# ionic router creates ionic-page-invisible and not removed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

`ion-router-outlet` creates an `ion-page-invisible` class on the routed component. It doesn't remove it on first load, as a result shows a white screen. Subsequent visits are fine, or a reload will remove it.
I tried manually remove the class as I found on the internet, but it doesn't work. This page-invisible is blocking the entire content. You can see the components inside the route on inspection, you can even click on it and it works accordingly but cannot see anything. I've tried rerouting to different components, it is the same. This happens on iOS/safari, mobile and desktop.

I also tried this using regular angular `<router-outlet>` and that works as expected but I cannot use that here for subsequent components.

My layout:

```
<ion-app>
        <ion-content class="ion-padding" [scrollEvents]="true" overflow-scroll="false">
            <app-navbar></app-navbar>
            <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
        </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

Output:

```
    <ion-router-outlet class="menu-content menu-content-overlay hydrated">
// ion-page-invisible is blocking the view
        <app-component class="ion-page ion-page-invisible">
//shows all the markups in component
</app-component>
    </ion-router-outlet>
```

Comment: We are facing the same issue in our application. Did you find any solution for this issue or still its open ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons I found out this may happen is when you have more than one `ion-page` nested.
e.g.

```
<ion-page> // <-- one here
  <ion-router-outlet>
    <route path="/">
      <ion-page> // <-- another one here
        <ion-page> // <-- another one here - This one must be removed!
          ...
        </ion-page>
      </ion-page>
    </route>
  </ion-router-outlet>
</ion-page>
```

Disclaimers: I am using with React. My module version `package.json` is as follows:

- "@ionic/core": "^6.1.5"
- "@ionic/react": "^6.1.5",
- "@ionic/react-router": "^6.1.5"

Something to do with the 'stack navigation' not working properly, in my case (https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#ionpage).